# understanding exceptions

Tags: php, exception

I have read articles upon articles trying to understand what exceptions are used for in php and I have gone through the answers already given in the forum. One of the answers which made atleast some sense to me is this one: [Are exceptions in php really that useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549344/are-exceptions-in-php-really-that-useful)

Here is a simple function for finding the inverse of a integer with and without using exceptions ([source](http://ulyssesonline.com/2009/10/18/understanding-php-exception-handling/)):

**With exception:**

```
function inverse($x) {
  if ($x==0) { 
     throw new Exception('Division by zero.');
  } else { 
     return 1/$x;
  }
}    

try {
  inverse();
} 
catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

**Without exception:**

```
function inverse($x) {
  if ($x==0) { 
     echo "I'm zero. Don't let me be the denominator."; 
  } else { 
     return 1/$x;
  }
}
```

So here is my question, **why and when should I use one over the other**?

Comment: You would (almost) never `echo from within a function`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various opinions on "when to use an exception". My personal opinion is:

- If you are working *with your own code*, theres basically no need to throw exceptions, as you then need to write your own handler for it - which also can be done without throwing an exception.
- If you are developing APIs that *other* programmers are using, it can be usefull to throw exceptions, so the developer using *your* code knows, that he has to take care of handling errors, AND gets an idea of what was the error-reason. (instead of just getting `null` he might catch `NumberToSmallException`, `NotANumberException`, ....)

In other words: When you already know how to handle an exception if it would appear - dont throw it. If the handling should be up to another developer, using your code - throw it.

Exceptions should *not* be used to control the flow of your application logic. Therefore use if / else statements.

But these are just my ten cents.

Comment: even if i am not developing APIs, lets say there is a functions.php file in my site where i store all my function definitions (which will be used by other developers). Do you think the use of exceptions would be appropriate in this case?

Comment: @user1463541: It actually depends on the function. Imagine a function that should store a file, and you call it like `storeFile(File file, String path)` - now the path is invalid. If you are using this function just in a very special case, you can handle it internally. If you are calling this function from different points of your application, where case-dependent error handling is required, an exception would make sense, because the store function then don't needs to be aware of every possible context (is it a image/config/userupload, etc.)

Comment: @user1463541 I would say: Definitely yes. Because why not? Document the function properly and everone, who uses the function, should be aware of the exception. Now (to reuse the `storeFile()`-example) it's up to the other developer, whether he checks for the file-existence in the first place, or handle the exception.

Answer (score 2):

> why and when should i use one over the other?

Oh, this is easy: You should never use "without exception" :) Don't misuse return values as status flag. Thats a bad habit from earlier days and only makes things more complicated, because then you have to check the return values and even their types over and over again.

If you have a function like `inverse()` the only thing it should ever do is to "inverse". If it can't do it, it's an exceptional situation, thus (you may guess) an exception.

To sum it up: Throw an exception, when there is a situation, that prevent a function/method to work properly, and that the function/method is not able to handle itself.

Comment: @KingCrunch : just to make it clear.. even if i use procedural or OOP, i should never use "without exception"?

Comment: @user1463541 Exceptions are a concept derived from OOP, thus _espcially_ in OOP you should use exceptions ;) And in procedural code I would use it too, but there is also the good old `trigger_error()`. However, the point is: When your function returns something, that a) has nothing to do with its purpose, and/or b) tells you something on how, or why something happened, the function should probably not return it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Especially when you use object oriented programming, exceptions are quite handy. For example, in an application where you use a DB library that throws exceptions for when it cannot make a connection. In that case, you can catch that exception somewhere, and you show a special page that tells the user that the database is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the best usage of Exceptions happens when there a method calls more than one level.

Think like I call method A, then it calls method B, and it calls method C. When this happens, if you do not use exceptions, method A must know all different types of error messages of method B. And method B must know about C's in the same way. But by using exception, method C's error can be caught easily without the help of method A and B.

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions should be used when your script encounters an error, in the example you can't divide by zero and so you have a logical error, so an exception would be appropriate.

Using exceptions allows you to see better errors messages and will help when it comes to debugging, rather than simply printing out a string which could be anything. Furthermore you can **catch** exceptions so you can detect when something goes wrong, whereas simply outputting a string isn't of much help.

Check out the [PHP docs on this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions are an invaluable tool when writing complex and/or extensible pieces of software, but saying that return values aren't good for reporting anomalies is IMHO an oversimplified and even dogmatic approach.

In this specific case it's perfectly reasonable to return a `null` value, as in "the inverse of the argument does not exist". For me the most important point is that `inverse` does not actually *do* anything; it merely *provides some information* (i.e. it is "read-only", it has absolutely no side effects).

Note that "absolutely no side effects" is also a good rule of thumb which means that you should definitely not `echo` from within the function unless echoing is why it exists in the first place.

If there were an expectation that after calling `inverse` successfully the state of the program would have changed and `inverse` cannot perform this change for whatever reason (perhaps it got passed bad arguments; perhaps a resource it needs is not available; etc) then you should absolutely throw an exception and let the caller decide how to handle the error.

Comment: "values aren't good for anything" Who said this? :? "the inverse of the argument does not exist" Thats not completely right: `1/0` is an invalid state and not just 'it doens't exists'

Comment: @KingCrunch: I 'm not sure why that wording bothered you, but I changed it to something hopefully more agreeable. As for "not exists", IMHO you are just being pedantic here and unsuccessfully to boot. Mathematically speaking, `1/0` is *undefined*. All languages that have a `null` value typically use it when they want to convey the idea of "not applicable/unknown/undefined".

Comment: Wouldn't say "bother", but I found it little bit "misleading" :)

Answer (score 0):

Think of it like this:

Sometimes, the value for `$x` comes from a user (eg. from an HTML form or something), in this case you would like to display an error (maybe something like `"The frobing level needs to be different than zero"`).

Other times, you are getting the value from a database, in that case it's kind of useless to tell the user about frobing levels or stuff like that, you will want to show an error page and log detailed information somewhere on the server (or even send an email to an admin).

With the second example it's not really possible to control what happens in case of an error (the same message is printed each time).

The right thing to do is to let the code that is calling your function decide what happens in case of an error. Exceptions are one way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 major benefits of using exceptions:

1. They go through the execution stack (meaning that if you have a few nested functions, you don't have to re-pass the error value, this is done automatically.
2. The first piece of code after a `throw()` statement is the code in a `catch()` statement. This means that you don't have to make hundreds of checks in every nested function/method you have.

Considering this functionality, using a return value is useful in simple cases (for example your case). In complex cases, where you have 10-20-30 different error messages that can appear in different levels in the execution stack, using exceptions is a must, or other developers(/even you in a few months) will have major problems when debugging.

That's my 2 cents on the issue, hope it helps.

PS: It's useful to log the exceptions in an `exceptions.log`.